# typescript inferring not working when arguments are passed

Tags: typescript

I'm pretty sure that both examples down below should be working.

```js
interface Test<S> {
  func1: (arg) => S;
  func2: (arg:S) => any;
}

function createTest<S>(arg: Test<S>): Test<S> {
  return arg;
}

createTest({
  func1: () => {
    return { name: "eliav" };
  },
  func2: (arg) => {
    console.log(arg.name); //works - name is recognized
  },
});
createTest({
  func1: (arg) => {
    return { name: "eliav" };
  },
  func2: (arg) => {
    arg; // type unknown, why?
    console.log(arg.name); //ERROR - name is NOT recognized
  },
});
```

the only difference is with arguments of `func1`

why typescript infers 'unknown' in the second example?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&target=6&jsx=0&module=1&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=false&ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gDwGUB8yA3gLABQyyMAriAgIwBcyAFHFAOYCUyAvIbgDc5SjToAmZm06NcPfsjggAnsLIBfcuTEIwwAPYhkCKBDiR0WPPmkdmlnAS73MjwqQrJTYalCPsONU0ychMzC1cWD1FaBil5dxFKLwgfP2JkEDgAWwhmACIIABtgOAA3fOR1NUp1ABoknUlWAITiJMoEQwx9IogAOiL9Dlt+rNyuQWQAemmAd30oAGsMZABaTJyUYFXTLo4QYAAvCAATJPrydUnQ03MIByjG2KYWzjbo5O9fIyJN3IKxVKFSqNSqDU8TSkrT4iU8lACU1myDAygADihaEsQPo5iA6sg5gALZQAfg6xm6vQGQxGATGW0mM2mAFEAEpsgDybPW-22qwAcpzUCl9ocTudPJcNDcyEA) (noImplicitAny=false)

Comment: Is `S2` serving any purpose here?  Are you not using `--noImplicitAny` in your code?  I'm hoping you can turn this into a [mre] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here)](https://tsplay.dev/Nd40vN) where the only issue is the one you're asking about, without potentially distracting things (like implicit `any` errors or unused type parameters)

Comment: Once that stuff gets fixed: This is a design limitation in TypeScript; the `arg11` and `arg12` have *context-sensitive* types, and so inference is *deferred* until a point until it's too late to have an effect on `S1`.   See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25825 and probably others.  I'm happy to write up an answer explaining this if you can clean up the code example first.  Good luck!

Comment: edited - noImplicitAny added in the config playground

Comment: Interesting to disable `--noImplictAny` instead of just explicitly annotating with `any`, but that's fine, I guess.  What's the deal with `S2`?  Does it serve any purpose in the question?

Comment: no - S2 is unnecessary here and was copied from a template. you saying that this is a bug caused by design limitations? this is pretty surprising as typescript is pretty popular and mature

Comment: So, could you remove `S2` from the question if it doesn't serve a purpose?  Yes, TypeScript has a [few known design limitations](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/search?q=label%3A%22design+limitation%22&type=issues).

Comment: edited. 804 design limitations is quite a 'few'. there is nothing I can do to overcome this?

Comment: You could annotate your callback params like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nrve3N), freeing the compiler from trying to contextually type them.  I will write up an answer.  But note, without a completely different inference algorithm (as proposed in [ms/TS#30135](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134)) you will probably have to manually specify types in a few places where you feel you shouldn't have to, no matter what.

Comment: thank you. feel free to write an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a design limitation of TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#11183](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11183) for an authoritative answer about what's happening.  There is also another similar issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#25825](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25825).

When you call this:

```
createTest({
  func1: () => ({ name: "eliav" }),
  func2: (arg) => console.log(arg.name)
});
```

The compiler can only possibly infer the `S` generic type parameter from the return type of the `func1` callback.  The type of the `func1` callback is immediately inferred to be `() => {name: string}`, and so `S` is inferred as `{name: string}`.  Therefore `func2`'s `arg` parameter is also inferred to be `{name: string}`, and everything works.

On the other hand, when you call this:

```
createTest({
  func1: (arg) => ({ name: "eliav" }),
  func2: (arg) => console.log(arg.name) // error
});
```

The compiler again tries to infer the type of the `func1` callback.  But now the type of the callback is *context sensitive*; there is an `arg` parameter with no [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations), so the compiler needs to infer the type of `arg` form the context in which the callback appears.  And, unfortunately for you, the current TypeScript inference algorithm **defers** inference here.  It decides to wait until after it tries to infer the generic type parameters (which is `S` in this case) before it comes back and uses context to infer the type of `arg`.

This fails spectacularly for your use case.  Your return value is of type `{name: string}` regardless of the type of `arg`, but because the compiler tried to infer `S` without it, the inference fails and falls back to `unknown`.  When `arg` is finally inferred it is correctly typed as `any`, given the context of the `createTest()` argument being `Test<S>`, but that's not what you care about.

And so `S` is `unknown`, and therefore the `arg` callback parameter of `func2` is inferred as `unknown`, and you get an error:

```
createTest({
  func1: (arg: any) => ({ name: "eliav" }),
  func2: (arg) => console.log(arg.name) // error
});
```

---

So that's why it's happening.  The inference algorithm TypeScript follows uses heuristics that often work, but sometimes they fail for certain use cases.  There is a discussion at [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134) about the possibility of introducing a "full [unification algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Application:_type_inference)" which could possibly work in a wider set of use cases.  That issue is meant to gather information about use cases that fail with the current algorithm to see if it would be worth the time and effort to implement.  If you really care about seeing that happen you might go there, give it a  and describe your use case if it isn't already mentioned in there (I haven't gone poring through it).

But pragmatically speaking, there's no way to tell when or even if such a thing will change.  Until and unless TypeScript changes, you should probably think about workarounds for your issue.

---

One workaround is to manually annotate the callback parameters so that it is no longer context-sensitive:

```
createTest({
  func1: (arg: any) => ({ name: "eliav" }), 
  // ------> ^^^^^ annotated
  func2: (arg) => console.log(arg.name) // okay
});
```

Now the inference happens the same way as the first example; `S` is inferred from `{name: "eliav"}`, and everything works.

Another workaround is to split the parameter object to `createTest` into one parameter for each property:

```
function createTest2<S>(
  func1: (arg: any) => S,
  func2: (arg: S) => any
): Test<S> {
  return { func1, func2 };
}
```

So there's a `func1` and `func2` parameter instead of a single parameter with `func1` and `func2` properties. The heuristic-based inference algorithm does some of its work in a left-to-right fashion for different function parameters; inferences made from the first function parameter can be used in the second function parameter.  So you get the behavior you want:

```
createTest2(
  arg => ({ name: "eliav" }),
  arg => console.log(arg.name) // okay
);
```

There may be other workarounds, but undoubtedly they all involve either refactoring to some different data structure which contains equivalent information or manually specifying types that you think the compiler should infer.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0&module=1&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=false&ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gDwGUB8yA3gLABQyyMAriAgIwBcyAFHFAObNwgCeAlMgC8hXAG5ylGnQBMzNp2a5BI5D14SyAX3LlpCMMAD2IZAigQ4kdFjz4FXNJhwF+zGy8KkKyC2GpQpuwcmjpk5OaW1s4s3lK0DPIqhLHIIHAAthDMAEQQADbAcABuOcha-AA0klQJcqzByWYmGEb5EAB0+UYcDh3pWfzkFZoRFlYQHrE1+kwNnE2pA9nIeYUlZRXVPvr1Dk0ILW2d3b3B-ZkQggD018jQUEZQw-yjZJETU3G1dHMO3HxFkQ0pdcgUiqVylUardkABaBGIwgAPVRqLUIBARjAEwAJjM6vJGsJCIcQK12l0en1ljc7kYANZwXgvN56BKGExmcbRLAyOwsAm-ImKDECEnIXDbeKyEWOZQS9TkNxOWwEYg1PwBUzA2aVH4IGTlUK6d48ybOGSCnzBCVLUGrcEbKHStScCVkiknannWnIWGM5nKsRAA)

Comment: wish i could upvote more then one time, thank you for the detailed answer!